# How do I record specific button presses to xml?

Tags: c#, ios, xml, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Yes, 
I am a noob, but I still do not understand - after a ton of searching the web, I cannot find the solution.

So
I create some buttons on my storyboard. I name some buttons colours and fruits - like blueBtn, lets pretend that it is the persons selected color. The other one is called banannaBtn, because that is the users favourite type of fruit. How can I record that they selected the blue button, and the banana, in an XML file? If you know that there is a tutorial that I am obviously not finding, feel free to send me the link! Maybe I am using the wrong keywords.

Haha the learning curve is big on these kinds of things.

Thanks,

Josh - a humble-d student

Comment: What steps have you tried to break the problem down into? I'd start by recording their selections in-memory, and then serialize that to XML (or JSON).

Comment: Create a sample of the xml file that you want to use and post it.

Comment: @john How would I record their selections in memory?

Comment: @jdweng I don't really have any particular format that I would like, I just am wondering how to get there. Eg: how would I actually record that the button was pressed?

Comment: You could create a class with a couple of string properties and when the user selects a colour, set that string to the colour the user selected, and likewise for fruits. Then you could use the xmlserializer to write this class to a file.

Comment: All the step are very easy.  There are a few decisions you have to make. 1) Do you write the xml as each button is presses or do you wait until the end to write the xml. 2)  Is the xml going to be "Well Formed" or Not "Well Formed" which means that you have one element as the root or the root element is an array.  3)Then decide if you are going to create the xml at the beginning of the code or at the end. 4) Next decide the format of the xml elements. 5) Finally design the button pressing code.